# VB.NET moving a button on click with If commands

Tags: vb.net

I am making this stupid little game where a button runs away from you when you click it. So I got it to move when I click it the first time but it won't move again.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    ProgressBar1.Increment(+1)
    Label2.Text = ProgressBar1.Value
    Button5.Location = New Point(424, 12)
    If Button5.Location = New Point(424, 12) Then Button3.Location = New Point(219, 80)
    If Button5.Location = New Point(219, 80) Then Button5.Location = New Point(12, 80)
```

On the second If  the  button will not move again. I couldn't find any other thread on this. Any help?

Comment: Do you have a typo...? Shouldn't `Button3.Location` be `Button5.Location`??

Comment: after you fix that, it looks like it will only ever move to (219, 80) and never to (12, 80)

Comment: It isn't a typo. The point is you click Button5 and it goes to the old location of Button3, So they replace eachother.
Also why will it never move to 12, 80?

Comment: In the last line of code, how can Button5 ever be at (219, 80) when you explicitly set it to (424, 12) two lines before (every time!)?

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You never set Button5 to (219, 80). You only set Button3 to that point.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change button3 to button5 in the first if statement.
2. Remove the statement `Button5.Location = New Point(424, 12)`
3. Change the `if` statements after the first one to `elseif`
4. Add an `elseif` statement to go from 12,80 to 424,12